# Gradle Plugin Test Project Build Failing

Tags: gradle

I downloaded the gradle plugin test project from their github here:
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/customPlugin

I also updated gradle to latest (`4.7`).

When I `gradle build` the `consumer` project, I get the following build error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'consumer'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not find org.gradle:customPlugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        file:/C:/Code/gradle/subprojects/docs/src/samples/customPlugin/repo/org/gradle/customPlugin/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-
  >   metadata.xml
  >        file:/C:/Code/gradle/subprojects/docs/src/samples/customPlugin/repo/org/gradle/customPlugin/1.0-SNAPSHOT/custom
  >   Plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
  >        file:/C:/Code/gradle/subprojects/docs/src/samples/customPlugin/repo/org/gradle/customPlugin/1.0-SNAPSHOT/custom
  >   Plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
  >    Required by:
  >        project :

What's the issue here? I guess I don't understand gradle plugins enough. Does the plugin need to be built somehow? I have no `1.0-SNAPSHOT` pat or anything of the sort, which seems to be where its looking.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the plugin need to be built somehow ?

Yes, at first, otherwise the `consumer` project won't find it.

Inside the `plugin` project, just run `gradle uploadArchive`

And then retry a `gradle build` inside the `consumer` project